# Conditional dependant probability question

Tags: probability

There are 3 vases of flowers. The first contains 3 roses and 2 carnations;
the second contains 2 roses and 1 carnation; the third contains 2 roses and 4
carnations. A fair die is tossed and the number that appears on top is noted.
If the number is 1, 3 or 5, the first vase is selected; if the number is 2 or 4, the
second vase is selected; and if the number is 6, the third vase is selected. A
flower is drawn at random from the selected vase.

(i) Determine the probability that the flower is a carnation.

(ii) If the flower is a carnation, determine the probability that it comes from
the first vase.

(iii) An additional flower is drawn at random from the selected vase. If the
first flower is a carnation, determine the probability that the second one
is a rose.

I have gotten the answer for part (i) and (ii) but I'm clueless about part (iii)

Comment: I believe that part (iii) is not presented completely, please check and give a full problem text.

Comment: Part (iii) looks incomplete.  Perhaps it should end "... If the first flower is a carnation, then what is the probability that the other flower is also a carnation" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Defining the events:

**C**: "A carnation is selected first."

**R**: "A rose is selected after a carnation."

**A**: "Vase 1 is selected."

**B**: "Vase 2 is selected."

**D**: "Vase 3 is selected."

Then it is asked for $P(R|C)=\frac{P(R \cap C)}{P(C)}$

P(C) you have already calculated in (i).

And $P(R \cap C)=P(A)\cdot P(R \cap C | A)+P(B)\cdot P(R \cap C | B)+P(D)\cdot P(R \cap C | D)$